# C++ Operator Error "Too many Parameters"

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

I have the following in a .hpp file

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Report&);
```

And this is my implementation in the .cpp file

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &, const Report &)
{
    // Implementation
}
```

What's wrong with my syntax? It highlights operator and says "too many paramaters for this operator function"

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that you have `operator<<` defined inside a class definition?

Comment: Yes, operator<< is inside a class, should it not be?

Comment: Not if you want to define both argument types

Comment: (Nearly) everything you want to know about fundamental operator overloading in C++ [can be found **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Comment: Mark it as friend. So: friend operator<<(...); in the header.

Comment: Friending it worked, thanks, if yall could upvote this so I don't have to make another account again, thanks yall